# RoR-software requirement for hosting website

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to deploying ROR websites.

I just want to know what are the software requirements **server side**, the requirements **client side**, and steps for deploying the application.

Answer (score 0):

There are no requirement in Client side.

In server side no requirement instead of Ruby. But it's more advice to use a Web-server ( Apache / Nginx / LightHttp ) and Rack compiliant server ( Passenger / Thin / Unicorn )

The step depend of what your really want deploy and in which environment.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side: this depends on the application you wrote, Ruby or Rails don't impose any client-side requirements.

Server-side: you need at least Ruby and a decent webserver like nginx or apache2.

If you're new to deploying your application I highly recommend that you check out Heroku. It's very easy to deploy a ruby application there, you don't need any knowledge about hosting or servers. Check it out at http://heroku.com